# PayPal IPN not working: Connected to language differences?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a piece of software that integrates with PayPal payments so my buyers can sell items on their website. So far, my buyers have been English, and IPN listener that works fine.

A buyer in Norway is not getting any IPN response - at least, the usual script for processing the data is failing but at this point I have no way to get server logs to know. The payment goes through fine, but the IPN pings are not being recorded.

The `checkout completed` pages are different for his language, and also doesn't redirect as normal.

I've looked through BOTH Google and Bing trying to find anything connected with IPN and language but cannot turn anything up.

My question is: My IPN script successfully handles English-language IPN messages. Is it possible that a foregone language is sending different variables or different variable names in the IPN ping?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: The variables would be the same, but a different language could have different characters in the values that aren't verifying correctly with PayPal in your code.  Based on that it's possible your script isn't processing the unverified IPNs the same way it does the verified ones.  Have you checked the IPN History in your PayPal or your PHP error logs on the server?

Comment: I don't have full access to the server (it's on a beta tester's site). I'll check with him. At least you've given me a direction to go in - I've been beating my head into the wall.